# How do I check the bitness of Outlook in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'm trying to build a script that installs Mimecast for Outlook depending on which version of Outlook is installed (32-bit or 64-bit.) but I'm not really sure how to go about this.

Initially, I tried having it check if Outlook was installed in Program Files(x86) using a specific path, and if it was, install the 32-bit version (if it wasn't it would install the 64-bit version). This worked on one machine, but I couldn't get it to work on others cause Outlook was installed in a different location. What are some other ways of figuring out if Outlook is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Answer (score 1):

Check the `Bitness` value in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\<ver>\Outlook` key (where `<ver>` is the Outlook version, e.g. `16.0`).
If the value is missing, it is 32 bit.

Comment: When in doubt, [check the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_registry_provider?view=powershell-6).

Comment: @NoahMerwin: Here's a unique idea: How about you do a search here for an existing question that explains how to read a registry value using Powershell? You've been pointed toward a solution - make an effort to figure out how to use it and learn something, rather than asking someone to do it for you. Learn how to fish instead of waiting to be handed a meal, and you won't starve.